# return http error code for curl in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, libcurl

```
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("curl -k -v --cookie cookie_name 'URL' -o filename")
```

Above is my code , I am trying to return http response code of curl. So i tried the following option -w %{http_code}

```
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("curl -k -v --cookie cookie_name -w %{http_code} 'URL' -o filename")
```

When i run it in python script and print status, nothing gets printed. 
Can someone please help me with the curl return code?
I want to try scenario's like when username password is wrong to get a status, or when the network host is not reachable or content not downloaded properly.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using Curl ? It's better and easier to do the HTTP request directly in Python (with a library such as Requests or even the built-in urllib or httplib).

Comment: i don't know the specific reason as i am trying to clean up some existing code. All i know is its a https request

Comment: In such case learn using some http related Python package, the easiest to use is `requests`. It will allow you to get status code and all what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As the other guys suggested, it is better to use HTTP to do a curl call. [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is the easiest way:

```
import requests

data = {
    ...
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print r.content
```

`r.content` contains the response body and if you need the status code just use `r.status_code`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I need to use curl as this involves cookie transfers

Answer (score 1):

`commands.getstatusoutput("cmd")` is equivalent to `{ cmd ; } 2>&1` i.e., stdout/stderr are merged. `curl` prints the http code to stdout. You could use `subprocess.check_output` to get only stdout:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import check_output

DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb', 0)

curl_cmd = "curl -k --cookie ... -w %{http_code} -o filename 'URL'"
http_code = int(check_output(shlex.split(curl_cmd), stderr=DEVNULL))
```

As others already said, you don't need to start a subprocess to make an http request in Python : you could use `urllib2`, `pycurl`, `requests` libraries instead e.g.:

```
import urllib2
from shutil import copyfileobj

url = 'http://httpbin.org/status/418'
# to load cookies from file, you could use cookielib module
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Cookie': 'cookie_name=value'})
try: # both `curl -k` and urllib2 do not verify ssl certificates
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    http_code = e.code
else:
    http_code = response.code
print(http_code)
if http_code == 200: # save to file
    with open('filename', 'wb') as output_file:
        copyfileobj(response, output_file)
response.close()
```